# Free Form pro to create ads forms

Tags: solspace-freeform

I like to use Freeform to create ads on my site - but i like to create member at same page.

So what I like is that first you enter email, then a ajax checks to see if that email is already enter in system (and the user all ready have a account)
if not the user proceed to login name, ads title, and all other ads fields.

Is that possible with Freeform Pro?

Comment: You probably want to use something like Zoo Visitor instead that ties together the member module and channel entries. While Freeform Pro is quite powerful, you'd need a lot of hacking to get it to create users and such.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel Can you move your comment to an Answer?

Comment: I suppose so. Wasn't sure if it was quite meaty enough to be an answer or not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/) instead of FreeForm.

While Freeform Pro is quite powerful, you'd need a lot of hacking to get it to create users and such.

Add-ons for the member module, like Zoo Visitor, Profile:Edit and Solspace User tie together the native member module and channel entries.

They would allow you to have users register and create the ads in their profile entry.